# Can you conditionally prepare tasks with Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have these two tasks:

```
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

task shadowJarW32() {
    ShadowJar sjTask32 = shadowJar {
        archiveClassifier.set('win32')
        configurations = [project.configurations.runtimeClasspath, project.configurations.implementationW32]
    }
    dependsOn(sjTask32)
}

task shadowJarW64() {
    ShadowJar sjTask64 = shadowJar {
        archiveClassifier.set('win64')
        configurations = [project.configurations.runtimeClasspath, project.configurations.implementationW64]
    }
    dependsOn(sjTask64)
}
```

I am trying to have `shadowJarW32/64` run the `shadowJar` task with specific fields that I have modified. It works perfectly fine with the second one, but `shadowJarW32` is run like if I ran `shadowJarW64`.

I found out that the issue was caused by the realization of the tasks, not their actual execution, so I thought maybe there was a way to only realize task `shadowJarW64` if I actually ran `gradle shadowJarW64`.

How can I work around this?

Comment: Stick your code in a `doLast`

Comment: ``dependsOn`` cannot be used in a ``doLast`` unfortunately

Comment: Of course it can. I suggest reading the documentation - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html

Answer (score 0):

```
task shadowJarW32 {
    doFirst {
        shadowJar {
            archiveClassifier.set('win32')
            configurations = [project.configurations.runtimeClasspath, project.configurations.implementationW32]
        }
    }
    finalizedBy(shadowJar)
}

task shadowJarW64 {
    doFirst {
        shadowJar {
            archiveClassifier.set('win64')
            configurations = [project.configurations.runtimeClasspath, project.configurations.implementationW64]
        }
    }
    finalizedBy(shadowJar)
}
```